# What would happen if a multi-layer perceptron is insufficient to learn a function?

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose that something is wrong with its configuration (ie topology), for example there are too few neurons in a certain layer, or not enough layers.

I have an intuition that some neurons' "delta" ($\Delta$) values will be fluctuating wildly without settling down to fixed values.  Is this a justifiable belief?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I'm about to, just wondering if there're some existing literature exploring with this aspect... :)